# Stop chrome from loading all tabs on startup in my extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to stop all tabs from loading when chrome starts up. I then
want to load only the tab I click on.

I was able to do this by using a content script in

#### manifest.json.

```
{
 "name": "blah",
 "version": "1.0",
 "background_page": "background.html",
 "content_scripts": [
   {
    "matches": ["http:// */*"],
    "js": ["stop.js"],
    "run_at": "document_start"
   }
 ] ,
 "permissions": [
   "tabs", "http://*/*"
 ]
}
```

#### stop.js just contains one line

```
window.stop();
```

Now this isn't ideal because, being a content script it stops loading
everytime, including when I click on a tab.

So, I tried doing in in background.html without a content script, but
I can't get it to work:

#### background.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script>

       chrome.tabs.getAllInWindow(null, function stopTabs(tabs) {
         for (var i in tabs) {
               var tab = tabs[i];
               //alert(tab.url);
               var stopLoading = {'code': 'window.stop();alert("stopped");'}; //alerts work here, but window.stop doesn't?!!
               chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, stopLoading);
         }
       });

</script>
</html>
```

How do I do this? Loading the clicked tab seems easy, but I need to do this first.

Comment: where is that extension? I would like to use it! currently what I do is use the "Tabs Outliner" extension and in tree I click on the big green "X" for that homepage, that wont remove the homepage from the tree, but will close it and remove from memory, so I can have as many tabs I want tracked and organized in groubs and subtrees, but I only keep a few open and running using CPU and memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this problem is related to [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=54257), if you star it maybe it will get fixed sooner.

Comment: What does "won't fix" mean? Makes no sense *LOL*, but looking at other bugs, it probably means "Won't fix because we don't want to fix it", right? ...this is a huge problem for me, because Chrome doesn't let me downgrade (not even on beta) and force-upgrades me on every new dev-build, just because I made the stupid decision to try one half a year ago. (And because I don't want to destroy / abandon my user-profile.) I am angry.